# TypeScript value constraint on a select element

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dom

I'm struggling with this for some times now.

I want to create a React select component where TS could infer the component's value type from a set of option values.

Let's say:

```
const myFakeValueSet = [
  "dc9d15ee-7794-470e-9dcf-a8d1dd1a6fcf",
  "1bda4f79-a199-40ce-985b-fa217809d568",
  "e91b2cac-48f6-4d60-b86f-ece02f076837",
  "66a9d7ac-9b25-4e52-9de3-4b7238135b39"
] as const;

const optionsWithTypedValues: Option<typeof myFakeValueSet[number]>[] = myFakeValueSet.map((fakeValue) => ({
  value: fakeValue,
  label: fakeValue
}));


const MyComponent = <Select 
  options={optionsWithTypedValues} 
  value={"something"} // should throw TS error
/>;
```

Here's an implementation which is working:

```
type OptionValue = typeof myFakeValueSet[number];
type Option<Type extends OptionValue> = {
  value: Type;
  label: string;
};
type SelectProps<Type extends OptionValue> = {
  options: Option<Type>[];
  value: Type;
  onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
};

function Select<Type extends OptionValue>({ options, value, onChange }: SelectProps<Type>) {

  return (
    <select value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

**MY ISSUE**

While the code above works as expected, **I have to extend the generic `T` from the `OptionValue` which is not generic**. So I tried to extend from the select default value `string | number | readonly string[] | undefined`, but if I do so, when I give an unexpected value (eg. `"something"`) to my component, it doesn't throw an error, and it changes the type to the original T union + `"something"`. It's like TS is inferring the type both from options'values and `value` (and `defaultValue` actually).

I'm trying to make it fully generic, so TS would know I can only set a value to the Select component from the options'set I gave him.

Is it even possible?

Original example : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-g34stp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myFakeValueSet = [
  "dc9d15ee-7794-470e-9dcf-a8d1dd1a6fcf",
  "1bda4f79-a199-40ce-985b-fa217809d568",
  "e91b2cac-48f6-4d60-b86f-ece02f076837",
  "66a9d7ac-9b25-4e52-9de3-4b7238135b39"
] as const;

type Option<Type> = {
  value: Type;
  label: string;
};

const optionsWithTypedValues: Option<
  typeof myFakeValueSet[number]
>[] = myFakeValueSet.map((fakeValue) => ({
  value: fakeValue,
  label: fakeValue
}));

type SelectProps<Type extends Option<string | number>[]> = {
  // I want to remove this extends to make it more generic, but keep its behavior
  options: Type;
  value: Type[number]["value"];
  onChange?: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void;
};

function Select<Type extends Option<string | number>[]>({
  options,
  value,
  onChange
}: SelectProps<Type>) {
  return (
    <select value={value} onChange={onChange}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}

const App = () => (
  <>
    <Select
      options={optionsWithTypedValues}
      value={"dc9d15ee-7794-470e-9dcf-a8d1dd1a6fcf"}
    />
    <Select options={optionsWithTypedValues} value={"d"} />
  </>
);

export default App;
```

This will give you what you need. The second `Select` component throws an error. The only change is I removed the dependence on `typeof myFakeValueSet` and a small change to here `Select<Type extends Option<string | number>[]>`.

Link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-crk21f

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo, I edited it.

Comment: If you already have `as const`, then you should be getting the error. And I do get the error in the playground if I just copy your code and paste it there.

Comment: Yes, if you read carefuly, the first example is the behavior I want. Note the `Type extends OptionValue`, this is what I need to get rid off to make it more generic.

Comment: Edited the answer to answer your question, I think

Comment: Thanks for that. You got it right: the answer lies there: `value: Type[number]["value"];`. As far as I understand, I was trying to think `Type` as the value type. In your answer, the Type is actually the whole options set type (which is an array of Option), so `value` refers to a specific litteral contained in the options set. 